# AWSIot Connection failed,certificates not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-iot

When I try to establish the AWSIot connection using SampleUtil class of iotClient. I am getting the below error in the Cloudwatch logs even though booth the files exist and have no permission issue. I am still new to AWS.Let me know what can be the issue.

```
Errors: 
Private key file not found:D:\xxxxxx-private.pem.key
Certificate file: D:\xxxxxxx-certificate.pem.crt is not found.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the files being in the external location. The code worked when I copied the files in the project folder.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear.

Can you modify SampleUtil class and add some debugging, else try to run some example java class listing and accessing those files.